# My sleep problems and sleep

Tags: mpi, sleep

I have a code that is supposed to wait for an input data file, distribute the data on a cluster, wait for the processing to finish, remove the input file and sleep until a new input file is provided by another application. Problem is the call to "usleep" of a few milliseconds makes the program go to sleep for 10-20 seconds. I see that mpirun is using high amount of cpu time during the sleep. I know that usleep requested time isn't always what it says it is, but I think there is more to it. That is something is wrong with my code (this being my first code in mpi).

Here is the relevant code:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myId);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs); 
bool newFile;

while (listeningMode) {
  while (!newFile) {
     inputfile.open(inputfname.c_str(),ios::binary);
     if (inputfile.is_open()) {
       newFile = true;
     } else {
       usleep(1000);
     }
  }
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

 // distribute data and do some processing here ....
 // and then at the end

   if(myId == rootProcess) 
    remove(inputfname.c_str());
   newFile = false;
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }   // while !newfile
}    // while listeningMode
```

Comment: What type of file is inputfile? Are all the tasks trying to read the same one?

Comment: It is a binary data file. All the tasks read the same file.

Comment: What filesystem are you running on? If its not parallel maybe its something to do with all the ranks trying to open the same file. You could try just reading with the root process and distributing to others to check this.

Comment: I am running on linux. I don't think it is a problem of competing processes as all processes read the file the first time the program starts and proceed to processing section. It is after the file is removed and waits for a new data file that the problem occurs.

Comment: Okay maybe try replacing usleep with a function of your own using MPI_wtime?

Comment: You need to explain a little more on your algorithm and setup. Is it just one process opening the file and calling the usleep? Are other MPI processes running on the same CPU? MPI_Barrier is likely to do a busy wait, causing the CPU to be busy. Why do you need an MPI_Barrier?